# Can I tell if a given URL is a Facebook Instant Article?

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

Given a URL, can I tell if it's a Facebook Instant Article without posting it on Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a request to the Graph API and request the field `instant_article` of the object.

For example a request for a NYT article would return the following result:

```
{
  "instant_article": {
    "id": "1060796090661757"
  },
  "id": "http://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/11/science/milky-way-light-pollution-dark-skies.html"
}
```

The request for this would be:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?id=ARTICLE_URL&fields=instant_article&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: I actually get the same answer from Graph API for both Instant and non-Instant Articles.
Request: `?GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?fields=instant_article&id=http://www.businessinsider.com/apple-releases-swift-playgrounds-for-learning-code-2016-6` (it's an Instant Article)
Response:
`{
    "id": "http://www.businessinsider.com/apple-releases-swift-playgrounds-for-learning-code-2016-6"
}`

Comment: I receive different responses. For example (using your URL) https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%3Fid%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.businessin%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bsider.com%2Fapple-releases-swift-playgrounds-for-learning-code-2016-6%26fields%3Dinstant_article&version=v2.6 - This returns the IA field, so it is an IA. If you try the same with http://www.google.com as the ID, the field won't be returned === not an IA